# Using outlook rest notifications api

Tags: rest, api, azure, outlook, notifications

I created a function in azure functions that is triggered by http request.
Also I have a web app that used for clients to subscribe to my app.
My app and web app is written in .net.
My goal is to set a subscription button in the web app, so when the user subscribe it would allow me to get push notifications about new mail in his outlook inbox folder and send http requests to my azure function that includes the content of the newly received mail.
I read the doc about this API but couldnt understand it and what should I do to get my goal. Also I didn't find any examples for this.
How can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

There are two options you can try for your scenario :

**Option 1:** you can create Function APP with [Outlook connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-office365-outlook) and Microsoft flow ( you can listen for new emails using Office 365 API -> "When New Email arrives" and also can be posted the payload using http trigger function

**Option 2:**
Creating Push notification in your app when you received, you can push the payload to 
Azure by a wehbook using Webjobs or Functions
Documentation Outlook REST API V2.0  : [Push Notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/notify-rest-operations)
To play around with REST API use this URL :https://oauthplay.azurewebsites.net

good luck